# Changing the value of a character in an array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to figure out how to change the letter "j" to a "Y" using a pointer in the program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char *buffer[] = {"ABCDEFGH", "ijklmnop", "QRSTUVWX"};

    printf("the value as %%s of buffer[0] is %s\n", buffer[0]);
    printf("the value as %%s of buffer[1] is %s\n", buffer[1]);
    printf("the value as %%s of buffer[2] is %s\n", buffer[2]);
    printf("the sizeof(buffer[2]) is %d\n", sizeof(buffer[2]));


    printf("the value as %%c of buffer[1][3] is %c\n", buffer[1][3]);
    printf("the value as %%c of buffer[2][3] is %c\n", buffer[2][3]);

    /*create a pointer to the pointer at buffer[1]*/
    char *second = buffer[1];

    /*change character at position 2 of bufffer[1] to a Y*/
    second++;
    second = "Y";

    printf("character at location in second is %c\n", *second);
    printf("character at location in second+2 is %c\n", second+2);

    printf("the values as %%c of second second+1 second+2 second+3 are %c %c %c %c\n",*(second),*(second+1),*(second+2),*(second+3));

    return(0);

}
```

How can I change a character located in an array of strings?

Comment: What happens when you run that code?

Comment: Trying to change string literals like that is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to write to string literals is undefined behaviour.

Change:

```
char *buffer[] = {"ABCDEFGH", "ijklmnop", "QRSTUVWX"};
```

to:

```
char buffer[][10] = {"ABCDEFGH", "ijklmnop", "QRSTUVWX"};
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a thing I noticed

```
char *second = buffer[1];

/*change character at position 2 of bufffer[1] to a Y*/
second++;
second = "Y";
```

You're trying to set to the string `"Y"` instead of to the char `'Y'`.

I'd do something more like

```
*second = 'Y';
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two things that are going to make this not work:

First, let's look at how you modify things:

```
second++;
second = "Y";
```

Think about what you are doing here: you are making `second` point to the string `"Y"`. This is certainly not your intent. You want to change the second character of whatever string `second` points to... there are two ways to go about that:

```
/* make the second character of whatever string the variable second to into a 'Y' */
second++;
*second = 'Y';
```

Alternatively, you could use the more intuitive:

```
second[1] = 'Y';
```

Now, even with this fix, your code will attempt to modify string literals, which will result in undefined behavior. Consider your code:

```
char *buffer[] = {"ABCDEFGH", "ijklmnop", "QRSTUVWX"};
```

At this point, `buffer[0]`, `buffer[1]` and `buffer[2]` point to memory that (*may*) be read-only. Whether it actually is or not is irrelevant though; you should certainly **TREAT** it as read-only. Therefore, the attempt to change anything would fail. To avoid that issue change things slightly:

```
char *buffer[3];

buffer[0] = strdup("ABCDEFGH");
buffer[1] = strdup("ijklmnop");
buffer[2] = strdup("QRSTUVWX");
```

And it goes without saying, but be sure to call `free` to release the strings pointed to by `buffer[0]`, `buffer[1]` and `buffer[2]` when you're done with them!

Comment: Man... everyone else types so fast!